# Simple Url Rewriting works with IIS Express but fails on IIS 10

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

This is the request:

```
http://localhost:8080/!/angular/angular-loading-bar/0.9.0/loading-bar.min.css
```

I want it to be rewritten as:

```
http://localhost:8080/angular/angular-loading-bar/0.9.0/loading-bar.min.css
```

Only change is, `!` in the beginning will be removed.

Here is the pattern I use:

```
 <system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="AngularJS Routes 1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="!\/(\S+)" />           
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}" />
      </rule>
      <rule name="AngularJS Routes1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Funny enough, it works with IIS Express but not with IIS 10, although UrlRewriting module was installed and enabled.
Even, under Inbound rules section of IIS, when I test the url it gives me the output as expected(removing "!"). But when I run the website it does not work.

Comment: I tried your rule with IIS 10, and it's working fine for me. I guess url with `!` is throwing 404, can you please check this paths, if it's correct: http://i.imgur.com/kO1S6iq.png

Comment: Link is not working. Please edit

Comment: Link is working for me, it has screenshot of 404 page

Comment: Yes, that's what happens. 404. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Ok, Can you please attach to question screenshot, what you see, when you accessing http://localhost:8080/!/angular/angular-loading-bar/0.9.0/loading-bar.min.css

Comment: https://snag.gy/dcf3qa.jpg

Comment: Definitely, rule is not working, it's not even trying to rewrite your path, can you please check rules in web.config in `c:\Projects\TunnlReport\web.config` and confirm again that it's present

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148880/discussion-between-victor-leontyev-and-jude).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on our  discussion with @Jude in chat:

For some reason IIS didnt have  `RewriteModule` in IIS.

Repairing URL rewrite module helped:

Go to Control Panel -> Programm and Features. Find URL rewrite and repair it